# Binding many XML files to rows of Datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, rows

I have 30+ big XML Files with 20-30 kb size, from which some information must be displayed in the `DataGrid` as one datasource. How can I make a binding 1(or 2 or 3 files) file to the 1 row of `DataGrid`?

For example, this part of XML-file:

```
<NameId>4366527</NameId>
<TargetType>2</TargetType>
<TargetCost>21</TargetCost>
<Tag>11</Tag>
<SupplyingRate>100</SupplyingRate>
<SupplyType>0</SupplyType>
<Transparency>0</Transparency>
<Passability>100</Passability>
<HumanPassability>100</HumanPassability>
```

And this part of another file:

```
<NameId>6591314</NameId>
<TargetType>2</TargetType>
<TargetCost>26</TargetCost>
<Tag>11</Tag>
<SupplyingRate>100</SupplyingRate>
<SupplyType>0</SupplyType>
<Transparency>0</Transparency>
<Passability>100</Passability>
<HumanPassability>100</HumanPassability>
```

Must be displayed in one Datagrid:

```
<dg:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Orders}}"
         AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding">
     <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="NameId" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="TargetType" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="TargetCost" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Tag" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="SupplyingRate" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="SupplyType" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Transparency" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Passability" />
         <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="HumanPassability" />
     </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Comment: I think what you're asking is somewhat unclear.  What exactly are you binding to 1 row of the `DataGrid`?  If you mean that you want all the files to appear as one source, then you need to clarify what that mapping should look like.

Comment: You are right. I changed original question, I hope it's more clearer now.

Comment: I don't work with xml much, but it looks like you need to merge your files into a single structure before binding them.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to do is create a class to contain XML data, like this one:

```
public class MyData
{
    public int NameId { get; set; }
    public int TargetType { get; set; }
    public int TargetCost { get; set; }
    public int Tag { get; set; }
    public int SupplyingRate { get; set; }
    public int SupplyType { get; set; }
    public int Transparency { get; set; }
    public int Passability { get; set; }
    public int HumanPassability { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create the ViewModel for your DataGrid, for example:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyData> MyList { get; set; }

public ViewModel()
{
    MyList = new ObservableCollection<MyData>();

    MyData data = new MyData()
    {
        NameId = 4366527,
        TargetType = 2,
        TargetCost = 21,
        Tag = 11,
        SupplyingRate = 100,
        SupplyType = 0,
        Transparency = 0,
        Passability = 100,
        HumanPassability = 100
    };
    MyList.Add(data);

    data = new MyData()
    {
        NameId = 6591314,
        TargetType = 2,
        TargetCost = 26,
        Tag = 11,
        SupplyingRate = 100,
        SupplyType = 0,
        Transparency = 0,
        Passability = 100,
        HumanPassability = 100
    };
    MyList.Add(data);
}
```

MyList is a collection which contains all the data you read from your XMLs. Obviously, in this example, I populate it with data samples. You have to provide the code to fill it.

After that, you have to create your DataGrid. I put it in a Windows and the code is:

```
<Window x:Class="Temp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Temp">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```